# What is the correct way to import modules when I'm writing my own module in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-module

I've searched for similar questions, but what I've found doesn't work for me.
I'm writing the report of my analysis in a jupyter notebook (let's say `main.ipynb`). I want to import an external `functions.py` file with some functions that I use to plot some results. To be precise, my working directory has the following structure:
-`main.ipynb`
-**utils**
----`functions.py`
---- other files...

The `functions.py` file is something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def myPlot():
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
    plt.show()
    ....
```

and the first cell of the notebook is this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils.functions import *

myPlot()
```

When I run the notebook I get this error:
`NameError: name 'plt' is not defined`, although I have defined plt in both files (even if I think I really shouldn't need it in the `main.ipynb`).

S0, what is the correct way to import a package (`matplotlib.pyplot` in this case) in an external file? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the flaw in my code and I think it's worth sharing, so here I am.
Maybe for beginners using jupyter notebook (as me) this could be tricky to detect: once you've run the cell with the import statement, it doesn't matter if you edit your file `functions.py` and re-run that cell. The kernel has already imported a file with that exact same name, so it won't notice the difference even if you've made changes.

The solution I found (and I think is the only one) is to restart the kernel every time you change the `functions.py` file.